# Check linkedlist circularity

Tags: algorithm

I need a method that takes a linkedlist as a parameter and return true or false if it is circular or not.

ex:circular linkedlist means there is node pointes to any previous node. 
I forgot to tell some constraints, I can not use any datastructure or dynmaic memory allocations.
I can use local variables only and the alogrithm can be done in n steps as someone said to me (I am thinking now to use two pointers?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [Floyd's Cycle-Finding Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare).  There's a better explanation than I could give of it over [here](http://ostermiller.org/find_loop_singly_linked_list.html).

There are also a couple of implementations in C and Scheme with documentation over [here](http://en.literateprograms.org/Category:Floyd%27s_cycle_finding_algorithm).

Comment: That slownode vs. fastnode is quite nice and simple. Clever!

Comment: That second link is awesome, thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 1):

Standard hash count applies:

```
function has_loop(list):
    foreach node in list:
        address = address_of(node.next);
        element = hashtable.get(address);
        if (element == NULL):
            hashtable.put(address)
        else:
            return true
    return false
```

*EDIT: As per the accepted answer's second link, this works but is inefficient, meaning there are lots of more efficient solutions.*

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial.

```
previousnodes ← set()
previousnodes.add(firstnode)
currentnode ← firstnode.next
while (currentnode in previousnodes) || (currentnode != null):
  previousnodes.add(currentnode)
  currentnode ← currentnode.next
when (currentnode = 0) return false
return true
```

Comment: Hmm, this will not work if a node points at a previous node that is not the first node in the list.

Comment: yeah, it was not as trivial as I thought. But not really more so. :)

Comment: Cheery: Yes, this is better. It will work but it will require O(n) memory space.

Comment: The Floyd's cycle-finding algorithm is quite much superior to this one, I know. That neither is hard.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a classy solution to this problem myself and couldn't help but post it here (though I guess the original poster might very well have graduated by now). Beginning from the start node, just start reversing the list. If the list is not circular, the process would end up with Null and if the list is indeed circular, the process would end at the start node. So there it is, a linear time algorithm with constant extra space. Just reverse the list again to get back the original list.

Comment: Bah, the Max's second link already talks about this...